# How to add all external jars added in Eclipse when making a WAR (Tapestry)

Tags: maven, maven-2, tapestry

I'm running my Tapesry project from Eclipse. Then it complies and run on jetty. But i could not find the War file created. But if i goto command prompt and try to build the war file from mvn it will not know about the external jars (for Google API) i have included. how to include those files to MVN manually? or is there any easy way to find the jetty deployment WAR file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the external jars (Google API) then you must add the jar as a dependency in the pom.xml of the project.
Eg:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

For Json dependency to your project.
The same way add all the other jars which are dependent to the project `pom.xml`and then save. Maven will automatically download the dependent jars and it's transitives as well. Following command will do the same.

```
mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<project>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>google-api-services</id>
      <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-discovery</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev7-1.8.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I found this from "http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs". So you don't need to add each jar separately.

Add the above to your `pom.xml` and call `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true`

Comment: It's okay.... you are now having only dependencies from google, If you have dependencies of google,oracle,apache etc then you have to add them explicitly..